# Ranging Beacons in iOS 10

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth, core-location, ios10

In my app, I use Beacon Region Monitoring in CoreLocation.
The app sets 2 proximityUUID as region (they have different id),
and start ranging like following.

```
#pragma mark - CLLocationManagerDelegate

(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region {
     [self.locationManager requestStateForRegion:(CLBeaconRegion *)region];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager 
didExitRegion:(CLRegion *)region {
     [self.locationManager stopRangingBeaconsInRegion:(CLBeaconRegion *)region]; 
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
didRangeBeacons:(NSArray *)beacons inRegion:(CLBeaconRegion *)region{ 
    for(CLBeacon* b in beacons){
         //output only previous beacon if it's before regionout to previous region
         NSLog(@"%@",b);
    }
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
     //error
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didDetermineState:(CLRegionState)state forRegion:(CLRegion *)region{ 
   if(state == CLRegionStateInside){
        if ([region isMemberOfClass:[CLBeaconRegion class]] && [CLLocationManager isRangingAvailable]){
            [self.locationManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:(CLBeaconRegion *)region];
        }
  }
}
```

It works in iOS 8 and iOS 9, but it does not work in iOS 10.

[in iOS 8/iOS 9]

```
1.broadcast beacon1

2.[app]didRangeBeacons (beacon1)

3.stop beacon1 and broadcast beacon2

4.[app]didRangeBeacons (beacon2)
```

[iOS 10]

```
1.broadcast beacon1

2.[app]didRangeBeacons (beacon1)

3.stop beacon1 and broadcast beacon2

4.[app]didRangeBeacons (**beacon1**)
```

Is it a bug of iOS 10?

Comment: There definitely seems to be something different in iOS 10 with beacon ranging. I'm getting very inconsistent results with beacons showing up briefly and then never ranging again in the didRangeBeacons function.

Comment: Thank you for your trial and information!   I'm waiting to be resolved in an update ...

Comment: Did you file a radar for this issue?

Comment: @Thomas Einwaller :No ,I didn't yet. It occurs login error in the radar in my environment...

Comment: Maybe you should try it with iOS 10.1b2. I had different beacon problems with iOS 10.0.x (no region exit event triggered). This seams to be fixed in the latest beta of IOS.

Comment: I have less iBeacon issues after installing 10.0.3 (14A551)

Comment: @patrickS,@Philip Jespersen :Thank you for your information. It seems to be solved.I checked my App works in iOS 10.1. sorry for late confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I had the same problem in Swift 3 but I resolved it.

There seem to be two things (that are probably directly related):

- for iOS10 the advertising interval of the beacon might be set too high (set it to about 200ms and then it should work on both 9 & 10 as advised by dantastic on Macrumors)
- how I got it working again: I tested it on an iPad with iOS 9.3.5 and needed to change the Deployment target to 9.3. That showed it was working again both on my iPad with iOS 9, but... also resolved it on my iOS 10 devices.